# WCF Webservice with an ASMX interface returning a Stream

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, asmx

I have a WCF service for inter-system, inter-network integration.  The service was originally created with just the WCF SVC interface, but because of requirements that came to light after deveopment we needed to add an ASMX interface to the service.

Now, all of this has worked just fine so far.  It's only now that we've added two new methods to the web service, one of which accepts a `System.IO.Stream` as one of its parameters, and another which returns a `System.IO.Stream`, that we've encountered a problem.

The WCF interface happily works with these two Streams.  The ASMX interface, when referenced by the client as as Web Reference, appears to have created an abstract class in its auto-generated client code: `public abstract class Stream`.

Has anyone else tried this before?  I'm trying to figure out what my options are.  Right now I'd like to keep things as they are, if there's just one small component I'm missing.  If not, could I perhaps create two copies of these Stream methods, one that takes a Stream and the other taking a byte array, and add attributes so that WCF exposes one, and ASMX exposes the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Legacy ASMX Web services do not support streaming. It's a new feature in WCF for Large Data and Streaming.

A basic method to bypass this is to split up your stream into chunks and send it piece for piece.

You can achieve a similar behavior using WSE and MTOM, but I'am not sure you will have the same results. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529360.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I can understand that, but looking at what the WCF service is requiring I'm not actually using Streaming mode.  I return a Stream object, but don't stream it.  It just gets turned into a base64 array on the way, then back into a Stream at the other end, from what I can tell.

Comment: So, after consulting with my client it was requested that I just provide a wrapper function that replaces the Stream with a byte[].  There's set file-size limits of 50MB, and it's an entirely internal system so they're happy to wear large files transferred like this.  Thanks for your help.